# REGEX to get Nth word between two characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to get a regex to use in Data Studio, what I am trying to do is be able to pull out the following into custom fields so I would need 4 regex's for each one

**STRING** = first_Product (21) » second_Product_3 (64) » third_Product (53) » fourth_Product_4 (21)

**into**.

custom_field_1 = first_product.

custom_field_2 = second_product.

custom_field_3 = third_product.

custom_field_4 = fourth_product.

To get the first I am using

```
.+?(?=\()
```

To get the second one I am able to use

```
    \»(.*?)\(
```

Would anyone be able to helo with this

Comment: Technically `[a-z_]+` would work for you. https://regex101.com/r/h4JHe7/1

Comment: Thank you for your comment, when I was putting in the substitute values as an example, I should have added in UpperCase and sometimes it having a number, my apologies, I have updated the above with a more accurate example, thanks again for any help you might be able to provide

Comment: I see. Try `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?= \()`  https://regex101.com/r/xZUULq/1

Comment: What programming language are you using anyways? It would take additional post-processing to assign `first_Product` to `custom_field_1` especially if the input string can have the products in any order like `eighth_Product (21) » third_Product_3 (64) » sixth_Product (53) » Tenth_Product_4 (21)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex with a quantifier like `{2}` `{3}` to get the specific matches from capture group 1.

```
^(?:(?:^|»\s+)(.*?)\s*\(\d+\)(?:\s+|$)){2}
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole part

  - `(?:^|»\s+)` Assert the start of the string or match `»` and 1+ whitespace chars
  - `(.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any char as least as possible
  - `\s*\(\d+\)` Match optional whitespce chars and 1+ digits between parenthesis
  - `(?:\s+|$)` Match either 1+ whitespace chars or assert the end of the string
- `){2}` Close the non capture group and repeat n times (in this example 2 times)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yYEqZS/1)

Comment: Thank you, this worked great, thank you also for the great explanation

Comment: Thank you and just did it